# Finding the magnitude and direction of unknown Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

Can you give me some tips on how I will attack this problem?

The problem stated that $F_1$ is resolved in u and v axes, while $F_2$ is resolved in v and w axes, and lastly, $F_3$ is resolved in u and w axes. It is also stated that the components of $F_1$ and $F_3$ are equal along the u axis which is really a confusing part for me. The components of other given forces are also equal to their respective axes. The components of $F_2$ and $F_1$ are equal along the v axis and lastly, the components of $F_2$ and $F_3$ are equal along the w axis.
The problem asks the magnitude of $F_3$ and its direction with respect to x axis.

The confusing part for me is the fact that some angles are unknown and the statement regarding the equal components of forces along their respective axis also adds up to my confusion.

The answer for the problem is said to be around 349 N.

EDIT: The creator of this problem told that the inclination of w axis is one of the keys to find the solution of the problem.

[image]

Comment: According to my calculations, the statement that the components of $F_1 and F_2$ along v are equal is not consistent with the indicated slope of, 7/42 for $F_2$.

Comment: Do you mean 7/24?

Comment: I've never seen a physics coordinate system deliberately use non-orthogonal axes.  If the creator of the problem wanted to test your knowledge of trigonometry and geometry, he should have set up his problem as as a trig and geometry problem rather than a resolution of vectors in a non-standard coordinate system.

Comment: The creator of the problem told that the angle of inclination of the w axis should be determined in order to solve for the value of $F_3$. My problem is there are insufficient information about their angles.

Answer (score 1):

First just right out what we know:

$F_{1,u} = 250 \cos (50^\circ + 10^\circ) = 125$

$F_{1,v} = 250 \cos (30^\circ + 40^\circ) = 85.5$

$F_2$ makes an angle with the $x$-axis of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{7}{24}) = 16.3^\circ$

$F_{2,v} = 200 \cos (60^\circ - 16.3^\circ) = 144$

Well actually now at this point there seems to be a contradiction, so let's assume the given slope is a mistake and let's set $F_{1,u}$ to $F_{2,v}$ and see what the actual angle between $F_2$ and $v$ should be.

$F_{2,v} = 200 \cos(\theta) = 85.5 = F_{1,v}$

$\theta = 65.7^\circ$

I'll use $\psi$ for the angle between $F_2$ and $w$, $\chi$ for between $w$ and $F_3$, and $\omega$ for between $F_3$ and $u$.

$F_{2,w} = 200 \cos(\psi) = F_3 \cos(\chi) = F_{3,w}$

$F_{3,u} = F_3 \cos(\omega) = 125 = F_{1,u}$

Now here we're stuck, as we have 2 equations and 3 unknowns, but let's just use the answer given that $F_3 = 349$.

$\omega = \cos^{-1}(\frac{125}{349}) = 69.0^\circ$

That means,

$\psi + \chi = 360^\circ - 69.0^\circ - 10^\circ - 90^\circ - 30^\circ - 65.7^\circ = 95.3^\circ$, and

$200 \cos(\psi) = 349 \cos(95.3^\circ - \psi)$

And that we can solve.

$\psi = 33.8^\circ$ and $\chi = 61.6^\circ$

So $F_3$ is $79^\circ$ below the $x$ axis, and the $w$ axis $50.6^\circ$ left of the $y$ axis, and so $F_2$ is actually $5.6^\circ$ *below* the $x$ axis. This is all working back from the answer though of course, but at least now you know exactly what information is missing from the problem. My guess is that the slope given was meant to be for $w$ axis, since information on one of $\psi$ or $\chi$ is missing and necessary.

Comment: The creator of the problem told me that the angle of inclination of w axis should be determined such that if the two forces resolved in that axis, they will have a same component. The problem is, as you stated in your answer, there are unknown angles. What will be the other way to determine the said angle in w axis?